# "The C Compiler [...] is not able to compile a simple test program" using CMake and Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cmake, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently testing the Visual Studio 2017 RC CMake support for Android NDK C++ projects on Windows and encountered an issue.

When I try to generate the CMake cache with:

```
<cmake.exe> -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<install_path> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="<androidNDK_path>\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON" --DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" <source>
```

I get the following error (The same happens with clang if I don't force gcc):

```
The C compiler "<androidNDK_path>/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

Before that I get the warnings that the identification of the C and CXX compilers are unknown but I'm not sure that's relevant.

I get more errors for the temporary test project but they don't seem to give a lot of information like

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5):
error MSB4018: The "VCMessage" task failed unexpectedly.
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5):
error MSB4018: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater
than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

How could I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everybody who finds this post and has the same issue: the problem seems to be the Visual Studio generator. Also it seems like the Android toolchains requires an argument with the path to "make".  So to solve both I installed MSYS (http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) and changed the CMake command to:

```
<cmake.exe>  -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<install_path> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="<androidNDK_path>\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="<MinGW_path>\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe" -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON" --DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" <source>
```